# Create a unique ID composed of the current year number and an auto incremented value

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i want to create a Student ID number compose of 4 digit year and a 5 digit auto increment field. example: 2013-00001 and when the year ends, the 5 digit number will restart to zero (0)  example: 2014-00001.

Thanks, Metta

Comment: With MyISAM engine, you can do that easily. With InnoDB, no.

Comment: the problem is MyISAM is not supporting FOREIGN KEY....

Comment: is that possible using InnoDB?

Comment: You should use a trigger.

Comment: Create a subtable for the year with the ID column being auto increment (Year2013, then ID is Auto) (Year2014, then ID is Auto) will give you the numbers and isolate them, but not sure this is what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
create Table width two columns: Year,LatestNumber 

function generateStudentId(){
    $year = date("Y");
    $latestNumber = 0;
    $res = mysql_query("select * from myTable where Year=$year");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if($result)
        $latestNumber = $result['LatestNumber'];
    $latestNumber++;
    if($result){
        mysql_query("update myTable set LatestNumber=$latestNumber where Year=$year");
    }
    else
        mysql_query("insert into myTable values($year,$latestNumber)");

    $fiveDigitNumber = return str_pad((int) $latestNumber,5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $studentId = $year.$fiveDigitNumber;
    return $studentId;
}
```

Comment: is this the easiest and simplest way?

Comment: That's the way that came to my mind. There could be better solutions. I cant think of anything right now

Comment: Wouldn't `Max('LatestNumber')` achieve the same as the extra table?

Comment: We have no more than 1 row for each year. As you can see the LatestNumber will be updated for each year, so Max('LatestNumber') has no use here

Comment: I meant dropping the new table that keeps updating and using Max on `myTable`. Maybe replace the - but the ids should all be bigger as each year > last year + appended increment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StudentId table itself where you store all the data.

```
select LatestNumber from StudentIds where Year=2013 ORDER BY LatestNumber DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Keep the number separate from the year, so you can reset it on a new year by adding a dummy Year=2014, LatestNumber=0

```
$LatestNumber = $result['LatestNumber'];
$LatestNumber++;

insert into StudentIds (Year, LatestNumber, ...) values (2013, $LastestNumber, ...)
```

Add error handling in case of multiple queries etc...