# Create AutoIncrement ID with Current Year - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function

It maybe a duplicate question but I do not have enough reputation to comment on someone's answer. I want to create a user_id in this format 2018-00001, but when I implement the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15184995/10053046) it gives me an error.

```
syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)
```

This error is pointing out this line.

```
$fiveDigitNumber = return str_pad((int) $latestNumber,5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

I created a new table named **year_table** with two columns **LatestNumber** and **Year**, then implemment the function.

```
function generateStudentId(){
$year = date("Y");
$latestNumber = 0;
$res = mysql_query("select * from year_table where Year=$year");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($res);
if($result)
    $latestNumber = $result['LatestNumber'];
$latestNumber++;
if($result){
    mysql_query("update year_table set LatestNumber=$latestNumber where Year=$year");
}
else
    mysql_query("insert into year_table values($year,$latestNumber)");

$fiveDigitNumber = return str_pad((int) $latestNumber,5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
$studentId = $year.$fiveDigitNumber;
return $studentId;
}
```

Comment: u don't have to write return at  third last line 
return str_pad((int) $latestNumber,5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);

Comment: Oh the hell, you were right I didn't notice that.

Comment: The version of php may have mysql turn off but you should be using mysqli anyway. Another problem with your code is that you are not connecting to the database.

Comment: sorry I am new to PHP

Comment: This PHP method is prone to **race conditions**, ideally you should do this in MySQL only by using a VIEW which generates the `fiveDigitNumber`

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in a right way?

Comment: Yes but i cant answer because the question is closed..

Comment: @RaymondNijland As it should remain closed. The OP would need to ask a new question with their new code and they shouldn't overwrite this one as some end up doing.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner "As it should remain closed" i know i didn't say it was a bad thing this question was closed because you are totally right.. I should have mentioned in mine other comment that the topicstarter should open a new question.when he wants to ask for a better solution for this current code and maybe even refer to this question

Answer (score 1):

It is causing **T_RETURN** because you're using unnecessary **return** on that line.

> syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

It should be like this,

```
$fiveDigitNumber =  str_pad((int) $latestNumber,5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: it now says Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()

Comment: What is your current PHP version? Extension `Mysql` was deprecated in PHP 5.5. Use extension `Mysqli` (like mysqli_query).

Comment: its working now thanks

Comment: @Mihae you have many more things to fix about your code.

Comment: Yeah after sucessfully saving one user now it shows new error 'Only variables should be passed by reference' by calling the function again

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the return statement. A return statement is not required in a function call.

```
$fiveDigitNumber = str_pad((int) $latestNumber,5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: now a new error kicks in Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()